# flutter dynamic text directionality issue

Tags: flutter, text, direction

code to reproduce error:

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  bool isRtl = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Directionality(
              child: TextField(),
              textDirection: isRtl ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('click me!'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() => isRtl = !isRtl),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

steps to reproduce:

1. type 'some thing' into textfield
2. remove it #it works fine
3. click the button
4. type 'سلام دنیا' into textfield
5. try to remove it #see the error!

is there a workaround or fix for this error?

Comment: It works fine for me, what is the error?

Comment: @Mobina what version of flutter are you on?

Comment: I'm on `1.17.5` .

Comment: I'm on 1.17.5 stable too but it's buggy for me!

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the device/emulator? Consider trying on another device.

Comment: tried on two physical devices. problem is still there! can't delete 'سلام دنیا' after changing text direction.

Comment: Oh, I found the error when adding a space character between the two words. I posted an answer, check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1.** Set `minLines` to `1` and `maxLines` to `null` in the `TextField`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Directionality(
              child: TextField(
                minLines: 1, // this is new
                maxLines: null, // this is new
              ),
              textDirection: isRtl ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('click me!'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() => isRtl = !isRtl),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Solution 2.** Remove the extra character that is inserted when tapping on space key in rtl:

```
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  var isRtl = false;
  var _text = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Directionality(
              textDirection: isRtl ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (val) {
                  if (val.codeUnitAt(val.length - 1) == 8207 ||
                      val.codeUnitAt(val.length - 1) == 8206) {
                    setState(() {
                      _text = val.replaceAll(String.fromCharCode(8207), '');
                      _text = _text.replaceAll(String.fromCharCode(8206), '');
                      _textEditingController =
                      new TextEditingController.fromValue(
                          new TextEditingValue(
                              text: _text,
                              selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(
                                  offset: _text.length)));
                    });
                  }
                  else {
                    setState(() {
                      _text = val;
                    });
                  }
                },
                controller: _textEditingController,
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('click me!'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                isRtl = !isRtl;
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it works but i need maxLines set to 1! is there any other solutions to this?

Comment: I don't think there is another solution other than making a new class for the text field. You can also set maxLines to 2 if it solves the problem. @AmirHosseinMohammadzadeh

Comment: max line has to be 1.. can you please tell me more about what you mean by making a new class for text field?

Comment: I've added another solution. It's a bit messy but it works. Check it out. @AmirHosseinMohammadzadeh

Comment: awesome! thank you for your great answer. it still has a little bug. if you long press remove button on keyboard you will realize it. I changed your answer a bit and will post it. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I changed [@Mobina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9902765/mobina)'s answer a bit:

```
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  var isRtl = false;
  var _text = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Directionality(
              textDirection: isRtl ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (val) {
                  if (val.codeUnitAt(val.length - 1) == 8207 ||
                      val.codeUnitAt(val.length - 1) == 8206) {
                    setState(() {
                      _text = val.replaceAll(String.fromCharCode(8207), '');
                      _text = _text.replaceAll(String.fromCharCode(8206), '');
                      _textEditingController.value = TextEditingValue(
                        text: _text,
                        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _text.length),
                      ); //changed here!
                    });
                  }
                  else {
                    setState(() {
                      _text = val;
                    });
                  }
                },
                controller: _textEditingController,
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('click me!'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                isRtl = !isRtl;
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```